# Term for staggered delivery approach (delivering service before total completion of the project)

Tags: business-language

If you go to a restaurant and tell them to bring whatever is ready first, what would be the business term for that?

Given a project, you are completing documents as you go - your client has asked you to send them as you progress through the project, what is the term for this delivery approach?

Comment: In software development, this approach is formally called [**incremental delivery**](https://www.gristprojectmanagement.us/software-2/incremental-delivery.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would use "Piecemeal" especially for the second example.